# How can I test keyEvents in Xcode Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, keyevent

I want to implement some keyboard actions into my custom view. The actual code is more complex, nut even in this simple setup I do not get that to work.

The code below is Swift 4 in an Xcode 9.2 Playground. If you turn on the live view a 500x500px rectangle should be drawn.

```
class MyView: NSView {

    override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext
        context.stroke(rect)
    }

    override open func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("Key pressed, Code: \(event.keyCode)")
    }
    /*
    override open func performKeyEquivalent(with event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        print("Key pressed, Code: \(event.keyCode)")
        return true
    }
    */
    override open func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    print("Mouse clicked.")
    }
}

let myView = MyView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myView
```

While a mouse click in the rectangle is detected, a keyDown is not. However, when you uncomment the `performKeyEquivalent` function, this works.

I have been spending the whole day on research, read the apple documentation on handling key events and the responder chain and read several articles on SO, but still have no idea, why my code isn't working.